# Need help with Cauchy's integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c_1(1)} \frac{\sin(z)}{z^{n+1}} \mathrm{d}z$ value the integral

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I need to calculate this integral with Cauchy's integral $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c_1(1)} \frac{\sin(z)}{z^{n+1}} \mathrm{d}z$$
by 1(1) a circle of radius 1.

Comment: Are we supposed to read your mind to know what $c_1(1)$ is?

Comment: If by $c_1(1)$ you mean a circle of radius $1$, centered at $z=1$ (i.e., points on $|z-1|=1$), then the integral diverges for $n\ge 0$ since $z=0$ lies on the circle.  If $c_1(1)$ denotes the circle $|z|=1$, then the integrand has a pole of order $n$.  Apply Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: yes! I suppose is a circule of radius 1. I'm sorry, my exam only says that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You titled this "Cauchy's integral" so I presume you know
the version of Cauchy's integral formula called "Cauchy's differential formula",
$\frac{d^nf(a)}{dx^n}= \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f^n(z)}{(z- a)^{n+1}}dz$

We can write $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int \frac{sin(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz= \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int \frac{sin(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right)$  where the integrals of
"Cauchy's integral formula" has a= 0 and f(z)= sin(z). So the integral is equal $\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n sin(x)}{d^n x}$.